# How to switch between 3G and Wifi for specific applications (both transmitters active) on Android device

Tags: java, android, operating-system, wifi, 3g

I've found this link which leads me to believe it is possible to keep both the 3G and the wifi data transmitters on at the same time.

http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/let-wifi-and-3g-connection-work-together-by-hacking-connectivityservice-java/

Anyone have any ideas how I could switch between them for different functions? Ie: let sms go through 3G, and video through wifi? I am completely new to this type of low-level coding, so a code sample would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea because of the significant battery drain that it would cause. Also I don't know of anything in the framework itself that would allow for this. You'd most likely have to at least code within the NDK. The article implies that the device would have to be rooted. Otherwise those chmod commands wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I understand the battery implications. I also haven't found anything in the framework that allows for this. It is apparently going to be in the standard for future OS releases (3GPP standard release 10). However I don't know how it will be implemented. So right now I'm basically looking for any type of "hack" that could get something like this going.